# Multiple conditions in loop

Tags: r

The following data is given:

```
M = matrix(c(1,6,"HOME_NET",1,0, 2,6,"OTHER_NET",0,1, 3,7,"OTHER_NET",1,0,  4,7,"HOME_NET",0,1, 5,8,"HOME_NET",1,0),
           nrow = 5,
           ncol = 5,
           byrow = TRUE)
colnames(M) <- c("A_NUMBER", "B_NUMBER", "DESTINATION" , "P1", "P2")
Mdf <- data.frame(M)
```

I would like to add an extra column which is set equal to 1 if A_NUMBER calls to a B_NUMBER in which B_NUMBER's destination once was "OTHER_NET" in P1 and "HOME_NET" in P2. For example, for B_NUMBER = 6, I would need to see a value of 1 in the extra column.

I tried the following:

```
Mdf$EXTRA <- 0
for (j in 1:nrow(Mdf)){ for (i in 1:nrow(Mdf)){ 
if(Mdf$B_NUMBER[i] == Mdf$B_NUMBER[j] && 
Mdf$DESTINATION[j] != Mdf$DESTINATION[i]) {
Mdf$EXTRA[j] <- 1  }}}
```

[image]

The problem is that B_NUMBER = 7, was equal to OTHER_NET in P1, and became HOME_NET in P2, which is okay, so it doesn't need a value of 1 in the extra column. How can I make this extra constraint? Thanks.

But I would like to get this:

[image]

Comment: It would be better to create a `data.frame` as it can store different classes

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description you basically want to keep 0 in `EXTRA` column if it went from `OTHER_NET` to `HOME_NET` rather than the other way around. One way to achieve this is to play with the signs (1-0 = 1 Vs 0-1 = -1). Using `dplyr` and converting your matrix to a data frame,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 arrange(B_NUMBER, DESTINATION) %>% 
 group_by(B_NUMBER) %>% 
 mutate(EXTRA = as.integer(sum(c(0, diff(P1 - P2)))<0)) %>% 
 ungroup()

# A tibble: 5 × 6
#  A_NUMBER B_NUMBER DESTINATION    P1    P2 EXTRA
#     <int>    <int>       <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#1        1        6    HOME_NET     1     0     1
#2        2        6   OTHER_NET     0     1     1
#3        4        7    HOME_NET     0     1     0
#4        3        7   OTHER_NET     1     0     0
#5        5        8    HOME_NET     1     0     0
```